# vscode intellisense fails in Typescript chainable method which return "instance or number", how to fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, typescript2.0

Consider the following code:

```
class BaseType {
    private _group: any = {};
    private _a: number;
    constructor() { }

    group(g?: any): this | any {
        if (!g) {
            return this._group;
        }
        this._group = g;
        return this;
    }

    another(a?: number): this | number {
        if (Number(a) === +a) {
            this._a = a;
            return this;
        }
        return this._a;
    }
}

class Another {
    constructor() { }
    checkChainable() {
        const inst = new BaseType().group({ name: 'test' }).another(20); //The intellisense is not working here
    }
}
```

the only why I could fix the Syntax error in the VSCode is change the return type to `this | any`

Is there any why I can solve the VSCode intellisense issue and compile time error?

Comment: In the example code, have you already made the change to the return type? What did the code originally look like?

Comment: @MattBierner, See the ```another ``` method (for original code). I have mentioned both type just for the sake of explaining the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by how union types work.

For `another`, the result type is either `this` or a `number`, so you can only use properties/methods on the result that are common between those two types. You'd have to do a cast or type check if you want to use properties specific to `BaseType`:

```
const x = new BaseType().another(10)
const y = typeof x === 'number' ? x : x.another(20)
```

You don't get an error in the `group` case because you are instead returning `this | any` which basically reduces to `any`, since `any` allows access to any properties or methods. However you won't get good intellisense for the same reason